# How to validate Schema in mule esb?

Tags: xml, mule, xsd-validation, mule-component

I need to validate incoming XML file based on XSD Schema. Is there any component to achieve tis task? How can I achieve this in mule esb?

Please suggest I'm bit new to mule., Thanks..,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following example :-

```
 <mulexml:schema-validation-filter schemaLocations="yourSchema.xsd" returnResult="true" name="Schema_Validation"
        doc:name="Schema Validation" />
```

and can refer your **.xsd file** against which your incoming XML need to be validate. Mule has a validation filter which will do the validation for you ..

reference :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/schema-validation-filter

Comment: Hi Anirban., 

     <mulexml:schema-validation-filter name="Schema_Validation" schemaLocations="C:\Users\Orders.xsd" returnResult="true" doc:name="Schema Validation" />
 --> defining as global definition

     <message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true" doc:name="Message">
           <filter ref="Schema_Validation"/>
       </message-filter> 

---> using in my flow 

But what is problem I'm getting is after message component(filter) it is dropping my payload(xml file) means empty file is forwarded for valid xml also. could you look into it please?., Thanks.,

Comment: Pls edit your question with your full Mule config .. and tag me after that ... will have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [XML Schema Validation filter](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/schema-validation-filter).

Answer (score 1):

reference :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/schema-validation-filter

seems not working here as for the code snippet as follows the error as below still is being received.

Code snippet used as per documentation:

```
 <message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true" doc:name="Message">
                            <mulexml:schema-validation-filter schemaLocations="GetMasterOrganizationRecordByIDRequest.xsd" returnResult="false"/>
                        </message-filter>
```

The schema used for validation as below:

```
    <xs:element name="CustMDGetRequest" type="CustMDGetRequestType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="CustMDGetRequestType">
        <xs:sequence>  
            <xs:element name="CallingSourceSystem" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="SourceSystemId" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="SourceSystemNm" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="IncludeDefaultAttributesForSourceTypes" type="xs:boolean" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="SourceTypesToBeIncluded" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Filters" type="FiltersType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="AsynchronousRequestId" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/> 
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="FiltersType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Values" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Error received:

```
org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException: Message has been rejected by filter.


------
ERROR 2017-05-24 21:01:14,887 [[eip-vcits-mdm-processes-proxy].HTTP_Listener_Configuration1.worker.01] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Message has been rejected by filter.
Payload               : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                        <CustMDGetRequest>
                                                <CallingSourceSystem>AUTOPUBLISH</CallingSourceSystem>
                                                <SourceSystemId>348109</SourceSystemId>
                                                <SourceSystemNm>CUSTMD</SourceSystemNm>
                                                <IncludeDefaultAttributesForSourceTypes>true</IncludeDefaultAttributesForSourceTypes>
                            </CustMDGetRequest>

Payload Type          : java.lang.String
Filter                : org.mule.module.xml.filters.SchemaValidationFilter@435baa89 (null)
Element               : /eip-vcits-mdm-processes-proxy-templateFlow/processors/1/0/1/0/3 @ eip-vcits-mdm-processes-proxy:eip-vcits-mdm-processes-proxy.xml:43 (Message)
Element XML           : <message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true" doc:name="Message">
                        <mulexml:schema-validation-filter schemaLocations="GetMasterOrganizationRecordByIDRequest.xsd" returnResult="false"></mulexml:schema-validation-filter>
                        </message-filter>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException: Message has been rejected by filter.
    at org.mule.routing.MessageFilter.filterUnacceptedException(MessageFilter.java:113)
```

Answer (score 1):

The schema validation with the .xsd didn't work for me but the validation with regex worked for me as show below for above stated problem statement.

```
<set-variable variableName="CallingSrcSys" value="#[xpath3('//CallingSourceSystem')]" doc:name="Variable-callingSrcSystem"/>
                <validation:matches-regex value="#[flowVars.CallingSrcSys]" regex="^[a-zA-Z]{0,14}+$" doc:name="Validation-CallingSrcSys"/>
                <set-variable variableName="MandatoryFieldRestrictionLevel" value="#[xpath3('//MandatoryFieldRestrictionLevel')]" doc:name="var-MandatoryFieldRestrictionLevel"/>
                <validation:matches-regex value="#[flowVars.MandatoryFieldRestrictionLevel]"  doc:name="Validation-MandatoryFieldRestrictionLevel" regex="^\s*\d*\s*$"/>
                <set-variable variableName="MinimumSearchScore" value="#[xpath3('//MinimumSearchScore')]" doc:name="var-MinimumSearchScore"/>
                <validation:matches-regex value="#[flowVars.MinimumSearchScore]" regex="^[a-zA-Z]{0,14}+$" doc:name="Validation-MinimumSearchScore"/>
```